# When I click to show flutter awesome dialog it doesn't work

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

When you click on the button to show awesome dialog, transparency appears over the application screen, but awesome dialog does not appear

```js
      void askDoAgain() {
        AwesomeDialog(
          context: context,
          headerAnimationLoop: false,
          dialogType: DialogType.question,
          animType: AnimType.topSlide,
          title: trans(context, 'make_another_transaction'),
          desc: trans(context, 'start_new_transaction'),
          btnCancelText: trans(context, 'cancel'),
          btnOkText: trans(context, 'ok'),
          btnCancelOnPress: () {
            // Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          btnCancelColor: Colors.grey[600],
          btnOkColor: colors.primaryColor,
          btnOkOnPress: () async {
            customerName.clear();
            customerPhone.clear();
            customerLocation.clear();
            _btnController.reset();
          },
        ).show();
      }


 function: () {
              askDoAgain();

            }
```

Comment: I think you need to use the "cascade notation" `..` operator like shown in their documentation https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_dialog#example, so it should be `..show()`.

Comment: @TijnvdEijnde I do the same problem too !

Comment: Can you try it like so `onPressed: () => AwesomeDialog().show`? Where `onPressed` is the property of the button.

Comment: I tried that and same problem @TijnvdEijnde

Comment: I have added an answer with a working example, this should do the trick, if it works for you can you please accept the answer? If it doesn't work are you getting any error messages?

Comment: So it appears to me and there are no errors https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WUDo0qmEWyf-AYEcQuMz42WjplIV7yfr/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

i think using the wrong context which show the AwesomeDialog.Make sure you have access to the correct context within the scope of the function askDoAgain().i modified your code just check it

```
void askDoAgain(BuildContext context) { // Add the 'BuildContext' parameter
  AwesomeDialog(
    context: context,
    headerAnimationLoop: false,
    dialogType: DialogType.question,
    animType: AnimType.topSlide,
    title: trans(context, 'make_another_transaction'),
    desc: trans(context, 'start_new_transaction'),
    btnCancelText: trans(context, 'cancel'),
    btnOkText: trans(context, 'ok'),
    btnCancelOnPress: () {
      Navigator.pop(context); // You can uncomment this line if needed
    },
    btnCancelColor: Colors.grey[600],
    btnOkColor: colors.primaryColor,
    btnOkOnPress: () async {
      customerName.clear();
      customerPhone.clear();
      customerLocation.clear();
      _btnController.reset();
      Navigator.pop(context); // Close the dialog after successful action
    },
  ).show();
}
//Then, make sure you're calling the askDoAgain() function with the correct context when you want to show the AwesomeDialog
    FlatButton(
  onPressed: () {
    askDoAgain(context); // Pass the context to the function
  },
  child: Text('Show Dialog'),
),
```

Comment: I tried that and same problem

Comment: what problem acutally you are facing right now kindly mention that

Comment: use this then 

**body: Center(
          child: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  askDoAgain(context); // Pass the context to the function
                },
                child: Text('Show Dialog'),
              );
            },
          ),**

Comment: That's how it appears to me                                                 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WUDo0qmEWyf-AYEcQuMz42WjplIV7yfr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you the current screen code?

Comment: I just solved the problem
The solution was just to add width to AwesomeDialog

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to work for me, I had to comment some of your code because I was missing the functions/classes:

```dart
import 'package:awesome_dialog/awesome_dialog.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => AwesomeDialog(
            context: context,
            headerAnimationLoop: false,
            dialogType: DialogType.question,
            animType: AnimType.topSlide,
            // title: trans(context, 'make_another_transaction'),
            // desc: trans(context, 'start_new_transaction'),
            // btnCancelText: trans(context, 'cancel'),
            // btnOkText: trans(context, 'ok'),
            btnCancelOnPress: () {
              // Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            btnCancelColor: Colors.grey[600],
            // btnOkColor: colors.primaryColor,
            btnOkOnPress: () async {
              // customerName.clear();
              // customerPhone.clear();
              // customerLocation.clear();
              // _btnController.reset();
            },
          ).show(),
          child: Text('Awesome Dialog'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What I think what was going wrong is that you were not providing the right context. Whenever you want to display a Dialog you need to make sure that the provided context is from a `Material` widget. In the case of this example, I am providing the context from the `Scaffold` widget which is a `Material` widget.

[image: awesome dialog example]

Comment: That's how it appears to me                                                 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WUDo0qmEWyf-AYEcQuMz42WjplIV7yfr/view?usp=sharing